# Не работает обработка нажатия кнопки через ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, mvc

По нажатию на `ajax`-кнопку выводит `PartialView` не на этой станице, а открывает новое окно. Что не так?

**View**

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ajaxIT" }))
{

```
        <div id="ajaxIT">
            @Html.Partial("AddRepField", Model)
        </div>
            <input type="submit" name="Add" value="add" class="btn-sm btn-default"  />}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Add(EventDetailsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel.Event.Repertoires == null)
        {
            viewModel.Event.Repertoires = new List<Repertoire>();
        }
        viewModel.Event.Repertoires.Add(new Repertoire());
        return PartialView("AddRepField", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: А вью с `@using (Ajax.BeginForm(...` какому контроллеру и акшону соответствует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл

> костыль, танец с бубном, карго-культ

своей проблемы. в _layout подключал скрипт:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

А надо было:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, почему эта замена минимизированного скрипта на неминимизированный является решением.

Comment: Понятия не имею, облазил весь интернет, потом заметил что все подключают не минимизированный, попробовал дописать - заработало!

Comment: В таком случае, следует использовать не слово "решение", а на выбор: костыль, танец с бубном, карго-культ.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен другой перегруженный вариант [Ajax.BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions%29) с указанием контроллера и метода:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Repertoire", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ajaxIT" })) {
  ...
}
```